# How to resolve Windows Update Error 8024402F on Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, dd-wrt

I have been having the same problem with Windows Updates on 2 of my machines at home, both running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. One of the 2 machines is a brand new install, the other has run Windows Update in the past, but is also not working now.

When I manually check for updates using the Control Panel, I get **error code 8024402F**:

[image: windows update error code 8024402F]

I followed the link to "Get help with this error", which brings up several articles in Windows Help and Support, none of which are for this specific error code. From the help and general googling I've tried:

- Checking internet connectivity. Most of the help suggests that this error is caused by a general internet connectivity problem. But if you're reading this, my connection is definitely working fine.
- Disabling antivirus temporarily and trying to run Windows Update. This didn't help (I run AVG free)
- Running Control Panel -> Troubleshooting -> Security Systems -> Fix Problems with Windows Update. This said it detected and resolved problems, but didn't help.

[image: windows update troubleshooter results]

- Update using IE (as I used to in XP). Go to http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/ redirects me to http://test.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/vistadefault.aspx for which IE displays a "connection problem" (i.e. site unreachable)

[image: internet explorer windows update not reachable]

I've had the same problem for 24 hours now, so surely the Windows Update servers haven't been down this whole time? A quick [check on twitter](http://twitter.com/#search?q=windows%20update) shows no worldwide outcry about Windows Update being unavailable, so is it just me? I'm based in the UK, but I notice that the http://test.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/vistadefault.aspx URL is also unavailable using ''wget'' from my webserver in Chicago.

```
day@ord1:~$ wget http://test.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/vistadefault.aspx
--2011-03-17 00:01:27--  http://test.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/vistadefault.aspx
Resolving test.update.microsoft.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `test.update.microsoft.com'
day@ord1:~$ host test.update.microsoft.com
Host test.update.microsoft.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

**Edit:** Output of ''ipconfig /all'':

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Office
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1C-C0-71-89-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a17f:ec64:9b37:92b9%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.102(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 17 March 2011 00:25:47
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 18 March 2011 00:25:48
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234888384
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-10-68-D4-00-1C-C0-71-89-46
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2098:13b8:a9ec:3703(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2098:13b8:a9ec:3703%13(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

**Edit 2:** Suggestions from Microsoft Support:

Configure the connection to obtain an IP address automatically

1. Click "Start", input "NCPA.CPL" (without quotation marks) to Start Search bar and press "Enter".
2. Right-click the network connection and click "Properties".
   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Click to highlight "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" and click "Properties".
4. Check "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically".
5. Click "OK".
6. Click to highlight "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click "Properties".
7. Check "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically".
8. Click "OK".
9. Reboot the computer.

I tried that and IPv4 and v6 were both already set to these settings, rebooted anyway, error still there. I then sent my System Information and WindowsUpdate.log file to Microsoft, sorry but I'm not posting their contents here.

Will keep you posted on progress.

Comment: If you do not get it resolved, get free Windows Update support from Microsoft...https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?LN=en-us&gprid=6527&x=18&y=11&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Comment: Updated with suggestions from Microsoft Support

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Solved.

I haven't heard back from Microsoft Support since sending them my log files, but I got some time to take a look myself. Here's a relevant snippet:

```
+++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
  + ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}, Server URL = https://www.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
Timeout for accelerated install is already set
WARNING: Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
WARNING: PTWarn: Anonymous plug-in skipped for WU
Triggering accelerated install by calling UpdateNow
No installable updates are available
WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efe.
WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efe. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for <http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/common/2009/06/2803268_2cf7737e73bd31ae709b14a95c8d2ecb7eccfbf3.cab>. error 0x80072efe
WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efe
WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efe
WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efe
```

Note the failure to download http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/common/2009/06/2803268_2cf7737e73bd31ae709b14a95c8d2ecb7eccfbf3.cab.

I tried to download this CAB file from a browser, which didn't work. I then tried `wget` (in [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/)) which didn't work and reported "Connection reset by peer". I also had the same problem downloading the CAB file from Linux machines on my home network, so it was not an issue with the Windows machines themselves.

To cut a long story short, I finally tracked down the problem to my router, which is running [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/).

Apparently I must have enabled the "Filter ActiveX" option about a month ago and forgotten that I'd done so.

[image]

Given the [security problems with ActiveX](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security/security-pros-kill-activex-164), this sounds like a sensible option to activate, but upon reading the help... not so much!

> **Filter ActiveX**
>       Blocks HTTP requests containing a URL ending in ".ocx" or ".cab".

Yes... that would certainly cause problems! Unticking this and applying the settings to the router has cured the problem on both of my Windows machines, as you'd expect.

Thanks everyone for your help & suggestions, hope this is of use to someone else.

Comment: I resolved my issue by changing my DNS server settings to point to the google DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: Genius! Thank you.  I had the same issue with my router and completely forgot about blocking ActiveX.

Comment: Wow, this seems like a serious lack of research on the part of the DD-WRT guys. I can see blocking `.ocx`, but `.cab` files are used by a lot of software on Windows. I would consider reporting this as a bug in DD-WRT.

Comment: in my case, it was my transparent squid proxy installed on my pfsense firewall.  disabled it, and then the updates worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

Go to *Internet Explorer, Tools, Internet Options, Connections, Local Area Network (LAN)*.

Settings: If it's set to "automatically detect settings" switch it to "Proxy server"  (my Windows 7 machine says port 80).

Then try Windows Update, it should work now.

If your machine is set to "proxy server", switch to "automatically detect settings" and try again.

Comment: Unchecking “Automatically detect settings” under Internet options/Connections/Lan settings did the trick for me as well. It started to download updates immediately. Also the test.cab did work after this change.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem by switching from "Obtain DNS server address automatically" to "Use the following DNS server addresses" and entering "8.8.8.8" and "8.8.4.4". These are public DNS servers from Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: When I tried this in Vista Home Basic, it told me that those network addresses were invalid.

Comment: Ah - I think they are invalid for IPv6, but they worked fine for IPv4. So I unchecked IPv6. And now Windows Update connects fine. Hopefully I can switch back to automatic DNS once the updates are done - it worked fine until Service Pack 2 was installed and Windows Update updated itself.

Comment: Using DNS 8.8.8.8 fixed the 0x8024402f error immediately for me (I have had the error for ages, last updated 6/6/2013). The Windows Update Troubleshooter always says it has fixed a problem, but it did not fix the problem. I already had IPV6 disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a corrupted update repository.  Try this:

Start-->`Services.msc`

Stop the "Background Intelligent Transfer" and "Windows Update" services.

Start-->`Cmd` ('as administrator')

`rd %systemroot%\softwaredistribution /s`

Go back to services and start Windows Update service.

Try updates again.

Comment: Didn't help I'm afraid. At least not on the laptop. Will also try on the desktop. Would be odd if both had got corrupted at same time... but you never know ;)

Comment: @Day: NP it's always a good frist step.

Answer (score 3):

Click on your time and date (bottom right).  A window should pop up, click on the link 'change date and time settings'.  On the date and time window click on the internet time tab, click on Change settings button, then click on the 'update now' button, then click ok and exit the windows and now try your windows update.

Comment: A truly bizarre answer, is there a knowledge base article or similar that prompted you to suggest this? I tried it, but it didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: Albiet a bizarre answer, a lot of Microsoft technologies rely on time. For a specific example: Active Directory - if the client's clock is different than the server's clock bad funny things can/will happen.

Comment: It's not just Microsoft technologies. Active Directory uses Kerberos  (an open source protocol) which uses time to express ticket expiration.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things -
You no longer use IE to perform updates in Windows 7 (and Vista?), in fact I don't think the "correct" URL is http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/ I believe it is http://update.microsoft.com and just sends you to a page saying "Hey, you can't use this anymore!" .... but that is beside the point and I digress (alot).

I don't know how much information your willing to post but one place I would start is from your Windows box type:

```
ipconfig /all
```

And check the output for anything odd. Awhile back I had a client who had issues getting Windows Updates, turned out someone hacked/messed with her router and changed DNS settings.

What updates are you trying to install? I know SP1 has an "issue" with dual boot systems and some systems that don't have a system partition (but either is easy to fix).

Comment: Not using IE: fair enough, was just casting about for other options. Will check ipconfig and post if enlightening. Not trying to install any particular update - was just trying to run update for first time on the newly installed PC, which didn't work and led me to find out that it was also now broken on my older install on the laptop which used to work fine.

Comment: Have added `ipconfig /all` output. Looks fairly sane.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this article and following step by step (including the tools). I wasn't able to solve the issue by any of the other answers of this thread until I read the article.

[How to solve connection problems concerning Windows Update or Microsoft Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818018)

The article includes a Connection error code list, download links to the tools, CMD commands, etc. for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 & 8.1. It's really complete. I was able to solve my issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just got hit by this one. This happened right after I made a HotFix install (hotfix which did not say anything about rebooting...)

The problem was fixed just by rebooting the system and making sure my VPN was turned on.

Now that Firewall configuration is not bad if you're just running Linux!

Answer (score 0):

Well, disabling IP6 in the network connection properties, worked for me. I hope it does for you too !

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem [documented here](https://superuser.com/questions/555714/installing-net-framework-4-client-profile-breaks-windows-update) and all the possible solutions listed in this question didn't work.

It turned out the problem was the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and that replacing it with the [.NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653) made the Windows Update error go away.