# Installing .NET Framework 4 Client Profile breaks Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, .net-framework

I have a Samsung NC-10 netbook with a fresh install of Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit (it only had 2GB).

If Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is installed on it, Windows Update will always return error code 8024402F ("Windows Update encountered an unknown error").

As soon as I uninstall it, Windows Update works just fine again. Out of the four computers in this house, only this netbook has the problem.

**My question is:** How can I get the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile installed on my netbook and continue to have a functioning Windows Update?

----- More information -----

The hard-drive recently died on my netbook so I replaced it with a nice new SSD and did a fresh installation of Windows 7 Home Premium (SP1) - along with all the updates.

At some point I found that, when I ran Windows Update, I was greeted with error code 8024402F ("Windows Update encountered an unknown error").

Looking in `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log`, I saw the following issue:

```
WARNING: ECP: Failed to validate cab file digest downloaded from http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/dflt/2012/02/4913552_4a5c9563d1f58c77f30d0d5c9999e4b8bff3ab21.cab with error 0x80091007
WARNING: ECP: This roundtrip contained some optimized updates which failed. New Update count = 0, Old Count = 3
FATAL: ProcessCoreMetadata did not return any update to be committed
WARNING: Sync of Updates: 0x8024402f
WARNING: SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed: 0x8024402f
```

When I downloaded the CAB from the URL listed and opened it, it contained a file called `4913552.txt`. A search on Google suggested that it's related to Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Other people had reported problems with it breaking Windows Update, but they were running Windows XP.

I tried the steps outlined on the [Microsoft site for this error code](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80244016-8024402f-or-c80003fa), but it reported that there was nothing wrong.

I also found [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/258531/how-to-resolve-windows-update-error-8024402f-on-windows-7-home-premium-64bit), I tried all the answers listed but none of them made any difference. My router doesn't block ActiveX, changing my internet settings in IE made no difference, assuming it was a corrupted update repository didn't do anything (except wipe my update history), my date and time was correct, switching to Google's DNS didn't work and neither did disabling IPv6.

Figuring that this update was corrupted, I repaired it and nothing changed. In desperation I un-installed it and Windows Update started working again!

Brilliant!

I then downloaded [the full version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24872) from the Microsoft website, installed it and, thankfully, Windows Update continued to work just fine.

A week later I turn on my netbook and Windows Update is broken again with exactly the same error message and log entries as before. Repairing .NET Framework 4 Client Profile did nothing, removing it entirely solved the problem again.

Thinking this might be some odd Windows installation issue, I formatted the hard-drive and re-installed Windows. Same problem as before - as soon as .NET Framework 4 Client Profile ended up on the netbook, Windows Update stopped working and reported error 8024402F. As soon as it was un-installed, everything worked just fine again.

There are three other machines in this house and all of them have working Windows Update and this Client Profile. Does anyone know why it causes this netbook to break and, more importantly, how I can fix it?

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I un-installed `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` (to be absolutely sure), rebooted and then installed `.NET Framework 4.5`. Interestingly Microsoft deprecated the client profile in 4.5 so all you have is the full version. So far Windows Update has continued to work, fingers crossed!

Comment: I had this issue once... wracking my brain to remember how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/4/0/74078A56-A3A1-492D-BBA9-865684B83C1B/NDP451-KB2859818-Web.exe). It supersedes .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image from a working laptop, which will be restored to him the same.
Create an image from a working laptop by running `sysprep` it and restore it to the one that is not working.

[Sysprep Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824816.aspx)

[How to Use Sysprep: An Introduction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457073.aspx)

[What is Sysprep?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

[How Sysprep Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744512%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Video: [Preparing an Image Using Sysprep and ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx)

[Easy Windows 7 Sysprep and Imaging](http://elmaskubilay.blogspot.ru/2011/05/easy-windows-7-sysprep-and-imaging.html)

> Let’s begin;
>
> 1. First thing is first; let’s build your system as you like.
>      Setup all your preferences and install all your applications. Don’t
>      forget your updates and latest drivers for your system.
> 2. Once everything is set and you believe that your system is ready to be
>      deployed to your other computers, we can start syspreping your
>      computer. Open an elevated command prompt as “Administrator” and
>      type“cd C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep” hit the “Enter” key.“sysprep.exe
>      /generalize /oobe /shutdown” hit the “Enter” key.
> 3. Your system begins the sysprep operations and with the command that we entered,
>      the “/generalize” switch will prepare the image, take off all the
>      drivers from the OS which makes your image “Hardware Independent”. The
>      “/oobe” switch will show you the “Out-of-Box Experience after the
>      deployment of the image and finally the “/shutdown” switch will shut
>      down your computer after the sysprep process is completed.
> 4. Once your computer is shut down, boot into your “System Image” software
>      such as Acronis or WinPE for ImageX and make a “backup” of your
>      computer or “capture” an image with ImageX to a network location or to
>      an external hard drive.
> 5. Now it’s time to clone! Boot into your
>      “System Image” software on the new machine that you want to copy the
>      OS and this time do a “restore” or “apply” the image with ImageX.
>
> Congratulations, you have just syspreped and imaged a Windows 7
>   computer. You can now deploy an OS with all the applications and
>   updates installed in about 1 hour!As I mentioned, this guide covers
>   only the sysprep process and a brief explanation of the imaging
>   process. In the following posts, I’ll try to cover the imaging process
>   with details.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that all the other working computers have different hardware. One is a nettop, one a laptop and one a desktop. As such putting an image of one of those onto the problem netbook (which, I think is what you are saying) wouldn't work.

Comment: @Richard `Sysprep` clear the list of hardware and computer SID. After the restoration of the image will start a mini plant which will supply hardware detection. This is a common procedure, generally with system administration. See link.